# Getting an Exception in thread, pointing to the lines relating to double and method in my class

Tags: java, class, double, java.util.scanner

I'm writing simple java program that simulates a simple restaurant register/book system. I got it to work, kind of, but there's one problem I can't seem to solve. Once I run the program, register a new restaurant and then book it after, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "None"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Restaurant.calculatePercent(Restaurant.java:69)
    at Main.main(Main.java:254)
```

My Restaurant.java:69 is a method where I calculate the discount percentage comparing with the time frame where the discount is available for that restaurant the user picked.

```
 public void calculatePercent(double bookTime){
        if (Double.parseDouble(startTime10) <= bookTime && bookTime <= Double.parseDouble(endTime10)){
            discountPercentage = 10;
        }
        else if (Double.parseDouble(startTime20) <= bookTime && bookTime <= Double.parseDouble(endTime20)){
            discountPercentage = 20;
        }
        else if (Double.parseDouble(startTime25) <= bookTime && bookTime <=
                Double.parseDouble(endTime25)){
            discountPercentage = 25;
        }
        else if (Double.parseDouble(startTime50) <= bookTime && bookTime <= Double.parseDouble(endTime50)){
            discountPercentage = 50;
        }
        else{
            discountPercentage = 0;
        }
    }

    public void calculatePercent(String bookTime){
        discountPercentage = 0;
    }
```

My Main.java:254

```
restaurantList.get(restaurantIndex).calculatePercent(bookTime);
```

The variable bookTime is of type double and I declared it this way:

```
    System.out.print("Please put in the time you would like to book\n->");
    double bookTime = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
    if (bookTime > 100){
        bookTime /= 100;
      }
      else{bookTime = bookTime;}
```

This is the link to my full code on repl. I apologize for the mess. I'm quite new to java. 
[repl link](https://repl.it/@NutchanonCharnw/Dude-5)

Comment: The problem is you try to parse String "None" to get double. Check what comes to your 'startTime' and 'endTime' variables.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the log :-

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "None"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)`

It is expecting a valid number instead of a string like `'None'` when parsing to a double.

`parseDouble returns a primitive double containing the value of the string`

The else block in your code like in line `#98` `#99` clearly sets the `startTime` and `endTime` strings as `'None'` when they are not added by the user. When the same is to be parsed to Double, it throws the exception.

***Solution***: Find a different approach. Maybe you can set a flag like `is10DiscountAvailable` to true or false based on user's choice and then move on to reading and setting the start and end time for the discount.

**Add**: Your code could also use Exception Handling, it is helpful in a lot of cases. Try studying and including them in the code as there are a lot of validation checks required for the inputs in this application.

Answer (score 0):

Your else case executed somehere and in your `calculatePerson` method you parse stringinto double

```
if (Double.parseDouble(startTime10) <= bookTime && bookTime <= Double.parseDouble(endTime10)){
      discountPercentage = 10;
    }
```

that's why you'll get exception.

```
 if (ask10.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
       //.... your code
  }
   else{
      startTime10 = "None";   //<--------------------------- here
      endTime10 = "None";    //<--------------------------- here
  }

  //20%
  System.out.print("Does the restaurant has 20% discount time? Y/N: ");
  String ask20 = input.nextLine();
  String startTime20, endTime20;
  if (ask20.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
         //.... your code
  } else{
      startTime20 = "None";  //<--------------------------- here
      endTime20 = "None";    //<--------------------------- here
  }


  //25%
  System.out.print("Does the restaurant has 25% discount time? Y/N: ");
  String ask25 = input.nextLine();
  String startTime25, endTime25;
  if (ask25.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
         //.... your code
  }else{
       startTime25 = "None";  //<--------------------------- here
       endTime25 = "None";    //<--------------------------- here
  }


 //50%
 System.out.print("Does the restaurant has 50% discount time? Y/N: ");
 String ask50 = input.nextLine();
 String startTime50, endTime50;
 if (ask50.toLowerCase().equals("y")){
         //.... your code
else{
     startTime50 = "None";     //<--------------------------- here
     endTime50 = "None";       //<--------------------------- here
}
```